# SQLite count(*) how to get the result?

Tags: iphone, count, sqlite

i've done this code to count the numbers of row in a db

```
    int rows = 0;
if (sqlite3_open([[SqliteManager getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sql = "select count(*) from artheca";
    sqlite3_stmt *countstmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &countstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {              
        NSLog(@"inside");
        rows = sqlite3_column_int(countstmt, 0);
    }
}
else
    sqlite3_close(database);
return rows;
```

But the result is always 0.

So, I'm not sure if `rows = sqlite3_column_int(countstmt, 0);` is the right statement to get the number of rows... is it correct?

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error - the columns start with 0, not with 1.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: To execute a SQL statement you need to [call all these 6 functions in order](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html):

```
sqlite3_open()        Open the database
sqlite3_prepare()     Create the SQL statement
sqlite3_step()        Execute the statement
sqlite3_column()      Fetch the result
sqlite3_finalize()    Destroy the statement
sqlite3_close()       Close the database
```

You are missing the `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_finalize` steps.

BTW, you could use [`sqlite3_get_table()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html) or [`sqlite3_exec()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) for these simple queries.

---

From http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html,

> The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0.

Hence you should use

```
rows = sqlite3_column_int(countstmt, 0);
```

Comment: you're right, but using 0 in the function still return the same result... so i fix my post because this is not the point i think!

Answer (score 4):

you missed `sqlite3_step(countstmt);` 
before 
`rows = sqlite3_column_int(countstmt, 0);` in order to execute the query